# SQL Query to retrieve username on reference from a child table

Tags: mysql

I am working with MySQL. I have two tables, `fb_data` and `fb_not`.

Columns of first table are :

- id
- username
- useremail
- userpass
- fbappid
- fbapplink
- fbuserid

Columns of second table are :

- fk_id
- liked_one
- liker_one

> The `liked_one` and `liker_one` columns are referencing `fbuserid` of **fb_data** table. Simply they are foreign keys. What I want to do is, to get the names of `liker_one` column which is in `fb_not` table. And I want to get the names from  `username` column of `fb_data` table.

[image: Check this Image]

> This demonstration shows how the query should work. I want to get the user name of each liker from the fb_data table.

Comment: Can you export sql file of data so I can get query for you?

Comment: Ok wait let me do it

Comment: @PunitPatel here is the link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3Nu36NpXiu8SDlYQWtJLXFDcnM

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output in formatted text (not images)

Comment: The link have the sql file, with tables and data, and the desired data is to retrieve , names of every liker, from the fb_data

Comment: Hi Nadeem, Please check below sql query : `SELECT username FROM `fb_data` fdata JOIN `fb_not` datan ON fdata.`fbuserid`= datan.`liker_one`'

Comment: The data shared in question and link are different

Comment: Nadeem, try with add more data with different name to get accurate result.

Comment: Thanks @PunitPatel that worked for me, can you please put it as an answer so that I can mark it

Comment: @Nadeem I have put it as answer so you can mark it and also helpful to other too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your desired output by `inner` `joining` `fb_not` to `fb_data` twice; once for `liker_one` and once for `liked_one` as below .

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (
        t2.username
        ,'('
        ,t2.fbuserid
        ,') is the liker who liked '
        ,t3.username
        ,'('
        ,t3.fbuserid
        ,') post'
        ) AS Col1
FROM fb_not t1
INNER JOIN fb_data t2 ON t1.liker_one = t2.fbuserid
INNER JOIN fb_data t3 ON t1.liked_one = t3.fbuserid
```

`distinct` is used to remove duplicate rows.

**Result:**

```
Col1
----------------------------------------------------
nadeem(1234) is the liker who liked nadee(4321) post
```

You can check demo **[here](http://rextester.com/EIXUKL75867)**

Answer (score 2):

Simply join the table twice:

```
SELECT d1.username as [Liker], d2.username as [Liked]
  FROM fb_not f
 INNER JOIN fb_data d1
    ON d1.fbuserid = f.liker_one
 INNER JOIN fb_data d2
    ON d2.fbuserid = f.liked_one
```

Comment: what are d1 and d2 @Bave. And the liker and liked are the columns, liker_one and liked_one

Comment: aliases for the joined table fb_data

Answer (score 0):

Here is your requested answer. Thanks Let me know if I can help more.

```
SELECT
   username 
FROM
   fb_data fdata 
   JOIN
      fb_not datan 
      ON fdata.fbuserid = datan.liker_one
```